# Unreal not fully linked

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

I'm migrating from Unity to Unreal for a project. To familiarise myself, I'm following this tutorial.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/QuickStart/index.html

Within the cpp file, I keep getting errors. To list some

"pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed"
"name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name"
...

These are very likely the result of some things not properly connected between visual studio and Unreal. The code does compile and works as it should in Unreal, but it's a pain to develop without IntelliSense.

I tried reinstalling visual studio, using VS 2017 and VS 2019, starting a new project and in the end, even reinstalling windows but I keep getting this error. [Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6KKH.png)

Comment: I'm not that familiar. anymore. I was 9 years ago. I did check the includes. The thing is that I'm just following the tutorial linked in question and just copied the code in there. There should be nothing wrong with the code since it compiles, runs, and does exactly as expected. On the other hand, people with similar issues managed to resolve them by reinstalling, relinking, regenerating the solution,... So there's no harm in trying.

Answer (score 1):

[VTT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7860670/vtt) is correct.

Anyway, i checked the image you posted.
The error "pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed" appears when you did not #include something. You are trying to use `ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder`. Did you include at the top of .cpp or in its .h file the:

```
#include "UObject/ConstructorHelpers.h"
```

[FObjectFinder_UE4_API](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/UObject/ConstructorHelpers/FObjectFinder/index.html)

The problem is not in the installations you mentioned (VS, Windows, etc). You must check one by one the errors...

Comment: Thank you for helping me find a solution. I tried adding the #include before, and again now. This solves some problems but generates new errors and the code actually doesn't compile anymore.
In the docs (linked below) it says that it might give false errors since unreal uses a different way of compiling than intellisense. I guess that there's no real solution and I 
will have to accept the fact that there are errors showing.
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Development/VisualStudioSetup/index.html